# Name of French Social Scientist and Theory where life has five domains

Tags: reference-request, social-ethics, social-critique

I read of a french social scientist who believed life could be separated into five spheres, in which so many "points" (so much time) could be spent into each. From what I vaguely remember, the categories were government, social life, hobbies, etc.

Can anyone help me recall the aforementioned author and theory?

Comment: Possibly Émile Durkheim? He wrote of spheres in which social life develops, but more specification would really help. Sociologists love to speak about spheres, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the person you are looking for is Auguste Comte? Among other things he distinguished 5 different intellectual functions & 5 fundamental sciences.
Check http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/comte/ More information might be helpful.